# download NC pkg for OS - UNIX WARE

Tags: unix

please advice 
I need to find NC pkg (NetCat utility )for Unix ware,
NC pkg exist for linux but I not sure if NC created also for UNIX WARE 7.1.1

Klod

Comment: Hi @Klod, were you able to get NetCat working, or do you need additional assistance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would probably try to compile from source given the choice.  However, [this website](http://aplawrence.com/SCOFAQ/FAQ_scotec7getnetcat.html) has a [compiled version](http://aplawrence.com/pub/netcat/netcat.sco5.newer) that they claim will work on UnixWare.

Answer (score 1):

(If my rep was high enough I would just comment on dsolimano's answer)

To add to dsolimano's answer, you will need compile tools which can be retrieved here:
ftp://ftp.sco.com/pub/unixware7/713/ostknotes.htm

Normally, you would be able to download similar tools like this from Skunkware:
ftp://ftp2.sco.com/pub/skunkware/uw7/Packages/

Comment: Good stuff.  I think your answer stands fine on its own, but feel free to ping me if you want me to edit anything into mine.